# How can I invoke share feature of mobile browser with native javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add the feature of sharing my website to any other social media sites.

Soon I found this(https://github.com/fa-ge/NativeShare):
https://fa-ge.github.io/NativeShare/demo/index.html

It can invoke the native share in the browser.

However, this project is base on node.js and my website doesn't develop with node.js.

I wonder is there any way I can achieve this by the native javascript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way in https://alligator.io/js/web-share-api/

```
var reply_click = function () {
        if (navigator.share) {
            navigator.share({
                title: 'My awesome post!',
                text: 'This post may or may not contain the answer to the universe',
                url: window.location.href
            })
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('aaa').onclick = reply_click;
```